# How to run Linux Live CD from a portable hard drive

Tags: linux, installation, pclinuxos

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop and I want to run PCLinuxOS from an external hard drive. I don't want to install it on the external hard drive but want to run it's installation from there so that I can install it on my internal hard drive. The reason I want to do that is simple; my DVD drive is not working properly.

The live CD file for PPCLinuxOS has an extension of .sqfs. Along with this file there are two folders, a boot folder which is empty and a isolinux folder which has gfxboot,isolinux.cfg and vmlinuz and some other files also.

How do I run the Linux Live CD from a portable hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)  then boot from usb and perform the install just as if you booted from cd.